# TAS5162 example schematic questions

Tags: amplifier

I am looking at this schematic from the [TAS5162](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sles194d/sles194d.pdf) datasheet and I have the questions:

- Is the "microcontroller" used as an on-off button?
- Are the connections inside the red rectangle optional?

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

The original schematic is found [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sles194d/sles194d.pdf), in page 19. From a quick glance of the datasheet and the schematic:

- the microcontroller is there to read the outputs of pins 2 (/OTW - overtemperature warning) and 3 (/SD - shutdown) and take action.
- the [TAS5508](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tas5508.pdf) in the red rectangle is the IC that does the actual audio processing and outputs a PWM signal. So, I'd take it's not optional unless you have the audio in PWM from somewhere else.

Comment: thank you @Renan for answering and for editing my question I have TAS5162 IC and I am trying to make a PCB

Comment: ''The audio in PWM'' input you mean ? what if I could not get the TAS5508 IC what I have to do ? I seek for TAS5508 IC but I find out iti s an amplifier IC as well please can you explain more ?

Comment: @AlexSoprano I've never worked with this IC so I can't help you there, sorry. Maybe the datasheet can explain better.